# Memory efficient way to store 32 bit signed integer in Redis

Tags: redis

Since Redis try to parse strings to 64 bit signed integers, is it a good idea to store binary representation of 32 bit signed integer instead of radix 10 integer strings ?

In our system we have lists of many 32 bit signed integer IDs.

```
I can store them like
lpush mykey 102450  --> redis cast 102450 to 8 bytes long

or store it like 
lpush mykey  \x00\x01\x19\x32  ---> this is just 4 bytes
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Internally, Redis stores strings in the most efficient manner. Forcing integers into radix 10 strings will actually use more memory.

Here is how Redis stores Strings -

1. Integers less than 10000 are stored in a shared memory pool, and don't have any memory overheads. If you wish, you can increase this limit by changing the constant [REDIS_SHARED_INTEGERS in redis.h](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/redis.h#L82) and recompiling Redis.
2. Integers greater than 10000 and within range of a long consume 8 bytes.
3. Regular strings take len(string) + 4 bytes for length + 4 bytes for marking free space + 1 byte for null terminator + 8 bytes for malloc overheads.

In the example you quoted, its a question of 8 bytes for a long v/s 21 bytes for the string.

EDIT :

> > So if I have a set of numbers all less than 10,000 how does Redis store my set?

It depends on how many elements you have.

If you have less than 512 elements in your set (see `set-max-intset-entries`), then the set will be stored as an IntSet. An IntSet is a glorified name for a Sorted Integer Array. Since your numbers are less than 10000, it would use 16 bits per element. It is (almost) as memory efficient as a C array.

If you have more than 512 elements, the set becomes a HashTable. Each element in the set is wrapped in a structure called `robj`, which has an overhead of 16 bytes. The `robj` structure has a pointer to the shared pool of integers, so you don't pay anything extra for the integer itself. And finally, the `robj` instances are stored in the hashtable, and the hashtable has an overhead that is proportional to the size of the set.

If you are interested in exactly how much memory an element consumes, run [redis-rdb-tools](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools) on your dataset (disclaimer: I am the author of this tool). Or you can read the sourcecode for the class [MemoryCallback](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/blob/master/rdbtools/memprofiler.py#L80), the comments explain how the memory is laid out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please explain just a bit more about the shared memory pool. So if I have a set of numbers all less than 10,000 how does Redis store my set ?

Comment: @Aresn - See updates to my answer. If you are storing sets of integers less than 10000, Redis will be very efficient memory wise.

Comment: @sripathi-krishnan couldn't you plz specify how much bytes are used to store string keys? Is "len()+4+4+1+8 byte" applied only to values?
We need to store a really big data set of pairs string(43)=>int and need to evaluate the volume. Thanks anyway for the info!

Comment: Another question is whether shouldn't we multiply len(string) of 4 (number of bytes per a char in C++)? So str(40) becomes 177 physical bytes in memory? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are stored with a length, so it won't be just 4 bytes in the database -- it's probably stored as 4 bytes data + 4 bytes length + padding, so you don't gain anything.