# How to get all hashes in foo:* using a single id counter instead of a set/array

Tags: redis

### Introduction

My domain has `articles`, which have a `title` and `text`. Each article has `revisions` (like the `SVN` concept), so every time it is changed/edited, those changes will be stored as a `revision`. A revision is composed of `changes` and the `description` of those changes

I want to be able to obtain all revisions `descriptions` at once.

### What's the problem?

I'm certain that I would store the `revision` as a hash in `articles:revisions:<id>` storing the `changes`, and the `description` in it.
What I'm not certain of is how do I get all of the `descriptions` at once.
I have many options to do this, but none of them convinces me.

1. Store the revision ids for an article as a set, and use `SORT articles:revisions:idSet BY NOSORT GET articles:revisions:*->description`.  This means that I would store a set for each article. If every article had 50 revisions, and we had 10.000 articles, we would have 500.000 ids stored.

Is this the best way? Isn't this eating up too much RAM?

I have other ideas in mind, but I don't consider them good either.

1. Iterate from 0 to the last revision's id, doing a `HGET` for each id using `MULTI`
2. Create the idSet for a specific article if it doesn't exist and is request, expire after some time.

Isn't there a way for redis to do a `SORT array BY NOSORT GET`, with array being an adhoc array in the form of [0, MAX]?

Comment: Do you really want to get all descriptions instead of the last X ones? You seem to focus more on memory consumtion than on performance on getting your data, is it on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have a good solution.
As long as you keep those id numbers less than [10,000](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/redis.h#L85) and your sets with less than 512 elements(set-max-intset-entries), your memory consumption will be much lower than you think.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16139369/1537042) a good explanation of it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in an optimized way using a TRIE or DAWG better than what Redis provides. I don't know your application or other info on your search problem (e.g. construction time, unsuccessful searches, update performance).

If you search much more often than you need to update / insert into your lookup storage, I'd suggest you have a look at DAWGDIC [1] as a library, and construct "search paths" (similar as you already described) using a string format that can be search-completed later:

```
articleID:revisionID:"changeDescription":"change"
```

Example (I assume you have one description per revision, and n changes. This isn't clear to me from your question):

```
1:2:"Some changes":"Added two sentences here, removed one sentence there"
1:2:"Some changes":"Fixed article title"
2:4:"Advertisement changes":"Added this, removed that"
```

Note: Even though you construct these strings with duplicate prefixes, the DAWG will store them in a very space efficient way (simply put, it will append the right side of the string to the data structure and create a shortcut for the common prefix, see also [2] for a comparison of TRIE data structures).

To list changes of article 1, revision 2, set the common prefix for your lookup:

```
completer.Start(index, "1:2");
```

Now you can simple call completer.Next() to lookup a next record that shares the same prefix, and completer.value() to get the record's value. In our example we'll get:

```
1:2:"Some changes":"Added two sentences here, removed one sentence there"
1:2:"Some changes":"Fixed article title"
```

Of course you need to parse the strings yourself into your data object.

Maybe that's not what you're looking for and overkill. But it can be a very space and search performance efficient way, if it meets your requirements.

[1] https://code.google.com/p/dawgdic/

[2] http://kmike.ru/python-data-structures/